# How to delete specific id in a mongodb database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using nodejs,express, mongodb and mongoose here!
It happens that i am trying to delete some of the ID's that are inside the "followers" document...

This is the part of the model ( I am just copying this part because it is the one that interests me):

```
  var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     followers: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
})
```

I am trying to delete using this code:

```
try{
    let user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    user.followers.remove({_id: ObjectId(req.user._id)});
    user.save();
  }
  catch(err) {
    res.redirect('back');
  }
```

The req.user._id is the ID of the user which I am trying to delete from the "followers",
however, whenever I execute this, the page just keeps loading and nothing happens.=The follower that I want to delete is not being deleted. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: could you put console.log(user) after await. I dont think the await is finish executing. somehow your program stuck there

Comment: Sagar, thank you, I found the problem using the console.log!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `delete`documents within an Array by using `$pull` In single `Query`

Query :

```
db.getCollection('users')
  .update({ "_id": ObjectId("5bb4747f316fcf310f3ef0a4") },
    { $pull: { followers: { _id: ObjectId('5bb4747f316fcf310f3ef0a5') } } },
    { multi: true })
```

> Tested on `Mongo GUI`.

**Test on below `doc`**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb4747f316fcf310f3ef0a4"),
    "index" : "123456",
    "followers" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bb4747f316fcf310f3ef0a6"),
            "name" : "green"
        },
       {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bb4747f316fcf310f3ef0a5"),
            "name" : "green"
        }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for it! I tried this just now and it also worked! What is the point of that "multi:true"?

Comment: Also its delete multiple if match

Comment: You can remove if you required to delete only one value

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, so I found the problem:
It looks like after adding this "{_id: ObjectId(req.user._id)}" the followers were actually being deleted... The page did not stop loading because i forgot to put a res.redirect after the user.save()! =D
This is the code after I fixed it:

```
try{
    let user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    user.followers.remove({_id: ObjectId(req.user._id)});
    user.save();
    req.flash('success','Successfully unfollowed '+user.username +"!");
    res.redirect('/users/'+ req.params.id);
  }
  catch(err) {
    req.flash('error', err.message);
    res.redirect('back');

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
A.findByIdAndRemove(id, options, callback) // executes
A.findByIdAndRemove(id, options)  // return Query
A.findByIdAndRemove(id, callback) // executes
A.findByIdAndRemove(id) // returns Query
A.findByIdAndRemove()
```

for example 01:

```
Example.findByIdAndRemove(example._id, function(err, foundExample) {
    console.log("you removed" + foundExample);
})
```

for example 02:

```
Example.findByIdAndRemove({_id: numberOfId}, function(err) {
    if(!err){
       console.log("successfully removed")
    })
  })
```

for example 03:

```
Example.findByIdAndRemove({_id: numberOfId}, async function(err) {
    if(!err){
       await console.log("successfully removed");
    })
  })
```